# How do I inspect a sequential model that is created with LSTM in python code?

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm

I have an algorithm written in python, it is timeseries analysis using LSTM. My professor asked me to show the details of the model that is created in the code. How do I inspect the "model" here? Does it have some visualization of the model in the background?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a visualization tool in Keras called `plot_model`. You can use it to save your model as an image where you can see the structure of your model including input and output dimensions.

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

You can read more about it here: [Keras Visualization](https://keras.io/visualization/)

Comment: @csel No problem, hope it helped, but you should not use comments for saying thank you. If you like an answer you should upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)